# Calculating Statistics Within Matching Row Values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to calculate some statistics about bid data for a large dataset that is not formatted optimally for that, but fixing the formatting has become a bit of a rabbit hole in itself (I would seemingly have to learn elaborate Power Query stuff to make it work) so I am seeing if there are answers out there that can solve the problem directly and cut out the middle reformatting step.

I have numerous bid events, for which there are an inconsistent number of bid prices from various bidders. ***Within*** each bidding event (say, for all the prices for Bid Event 101), I want to calculate: mean, st. dev., the difference between the two lowest bids, and the standard deviation of all *losing* bids (i.e., all but the lowest bid).

My data looks like it does in my example, but much larger. How the solution is formatted doesn't matter, it can be ugly or repetitive so that multiple rows for Bid Event 101 would have the same answers over and over, doesn't matter. Do I *need* to figure out how to pivot this before calculating these or is there a way to do this without a wonky and complex pivoting where I need to write a power query to create multiple custom columns that maintain a ranking?

Version: Office 365 for Government, "Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111)"

Thank you!!!

Please see link for the image of sample data to get at what I'm after.
[two columns of data, one of bid events and one of bid prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYp61.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is just a longer table of the table in your image, then try this:

1. Create a unique list of bid event IDs

   =UNIQUE(A2:A7)
2. Create a formula for the stats you want. This relies on LET and the FILTER function.

   =LET(
   d,FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=$E2),
   one,SMALL(d,1),
   two,SMALL(d,2),
   av,AVERAGE(d),
   std,STDEV.S(d),
   diff,two-one,
   losingstd,STDEV.S(FILTER(d,d>one)),
   CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},av,std,diff,losingstd)
   )

First we filter the raw data for the unique event ID and store it in a name "d". We return the smallest and second smallest values from d into "one" and "two" respectively using the SMALL function. We calculate the average and standard deviation of d, and the difference between the two smallest values. Lastly, we re-filter d to remove the smallest value and take the standard deviation of the result.

Finally, we use CHOOSE to horizontally join the above statistics into a single row.

We then copy down the formula for as many unique bid events as are in the unique list.

[image]